# Inner product space as dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

Can an orthogonal basis to a finite dimensional space be represented as a dot product in the coordinates of the basis?

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you'd like to know?

Comment: Sorry, for example if we have a vector space V and a basis for V, B can we describe an inner product <x,y > as [x]B+[y]B? Does that make it orthogonal?

Comment: What does the notation $[x]$ mean?  And how are you defining the multiplication of whatever $[x]$ and $[y]$ are with the *set* of vectors $B$?

Comment: @Bye_World it seems $[x]$ means the coordinate vector of $x$ with respect to the basis $B$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the question you are trying to ask is:

> Given a basis $B = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ on a finite dimensional space, we define the function $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ as follows: for each $x,y \in V$, we may uniquely select $x_i$ and $y_i$ such that $x = x_1 v_1 + \cdots + x_n v_n$ and $y = y_1 v_1 + \cdots + y_n v_n$.  We then define
>   $$
> \langle x,y\rangle = x_1 y_1 + \cdots + x_n y_n
> $$
>   Is this function an inner product? That is, is the function that takes the dot-product of two coordinate vectors with respect to a given basis always an inner product?

The answer to this question is yes; the proof of this fact is routine.  Actually, it seems that your question is a little bit more specific:

> Can every inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be expressed in the above form for the correct choice of basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$?

Again, the answer is yes. The proof of this statement is a bit more subtle.

Comment: The answer is "yes" when the vector space has scalars from the real numbers, but of course not over a general field.

Comment: @KCd is this statement false over $\Bbb C$?

Comment: @KCd I was under the impression that every sesquilinear inner product could be written in the form
$$
\langle x,y \rangle = x^* A y
$$
for some positive definite matrix $A$.

Comment: Inner products are defined on vector spaces over the real or complex numbers (or fields sufficiently close to them in structure that the definition carries over more or less directly), but not all vector spaces in math are defined over such fields, e.g., think about vector spaces over finite fields.

Comment: For example, the dot product on $F^n$ is not "positive-definite" when $F$ is a finite field: there is no notion of positivity!

Comment: @KCd ah, sure. I tend not to think beyond the usual suspects (fields of char 0) when it comes to dot-products.